# Servlet is not giving output to jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am facing a strange behavior from my application
I dont understand why its showing an error and and also if the error is fixed its not giving any output

can anyone help me with this??

here is the error

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.arithmatic.pkg.Servlet01.doGet(Servlet01.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

Here is my code for servlet.java

```
package com.arithmatic.pkg;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Servlet01 extends HttpServlet {



@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



        String Num1= request.getParameter("Num1");
        String Num2= request.getParameter("Num2");
        String op=request.getParameter("oper");

        if(Num1.equals("")||Num2.equals("")){
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                out.println(" Fields cant be left blank");
               request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            request.setAttribute("Num1", Num1);
            request.setAttribute("Num2", Num2);

          if(op.equals("Add")){

              int op1=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num1"));
              int op2=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num2"));
              int r=op1+op2;
              request.setAttribute("result",Integer.toString(r));
             request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);


            }
          else if(op.equals("Substract")){
                 int op1=Integer.parseInt((String) request.getAttribute("Num1"));
                  int op2=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num2"));
                  int r=op1-op2;
                  request.setAttribute("result",Integer.toString(r));
                  request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);

                 }
          else if(op.equals("Multiply")){ 
              int op1=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num1"));
              int op2=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num2"));
              int r=op1*op2;
              request.setAttribute("result",Integer.toString(r));
             request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);

         }
          else {
              int op1=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num1"));
              int op2=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num2"));
              int r=op1/op2;
              request.setAttribute("result",Integer.toString(r));
              request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp").forward(request, response);
          }



    }
```

and Here is my jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Giving the input</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action ='Servlet01'>
         <center>Input No.<br>
        <input type="text" name="Num1" ><br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Num2"  ><br>
        <br>
        Select the operation<br>
        <Select Name="oper" >   
            <option>Add</option>
            <option>Subtract</option>
            <option>Multiply</option>
            <option>Division</option>
        </Select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate"><br> 
        </center>
        <br><br>
        Result=
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="done" value='<%=request.getAttribute("result")%>' /> 
</form>


    </body>
</html>
```

and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Webapp-01</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet01</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.arithmatic.pkg.Servlet01</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet01</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet01</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Plesae provide a minimal working example.

Comment: what is the screen ur getting when u run on server....provide the screen then we can resolve it....

Comment: Well, `<Select Name="Oper" >` vs. `String op=request.getParameter("oper");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top of your stack trace shows this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.arithmatic.pkg.Servlet01.doGet(Servlet01.java:33)
```

If I have correctly counted source lines in `Servlet01`, this is the offending line:

```
int op2=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("Num2"));
```

Therefore, it appears that the value for `Num2` is `null`, although perhaps my counting is off (or your code doesn't quite line up), because I'm surprised that the exception doesn't occur on the preceding line, for `Num1`.

There are 2 possible fixes:

1. Since you are using `GET` instead of `POST`, change all calls to `request.getAttribute` to `request.getParameter` for retrieving form data.
2. Alternatively, use `POST` instead, which is more conventional for submitting form data. Do this as follows:

   1. Add `method="POST"` to your opening form tag, like so:

      `<form action="Servlet01" method="POST">`
   2. Rename your servlet's `doGet` method to `doPost` (and leave your calls to `request.getAttribute` as they are).